# Pointers to structures that contain pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

Let's say I have a structure (datatype) as it follows:

```
typedef struct {
    int size;
    int *p;
} mystruct;
```

I declare a new structure as a pointer, because I want to pass it by reference to other functions:

`mystruct *hello;`

I have three questions:

1. I understand that to access the `size` variable I have to do it with `hello->size` or `(*hello).size`, and that if I refer to `p` throuth `hello->p` I will only access the first position of the `p` array. But... How do I use an element inside that array? Would be correct something like `(hello->p)[2]`?
2. Can I do `realloc` with the `p` array using that same notation (`hello->p`)?
3. If I pass `hello` by reference to a function and want to modify the content of its variables and arrays... Is it enough to do `hello->size = 3` to make the change effective in the whole program? How can I refer to the elements of the array `p`?

I'd appreciate any hint on the matter!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### edit

You edited your question, now p is a pointer, not an array.

1. Yes, and you can omit the parenthesis.
2. Yes, but you must have called `malloc` to allocate memory for it before calling `realloc`.

   *edit*

   Or you could initialize `hello->p` to `NULL`, so that calling `realloc(hello->p, someSize)` will return the same value as `malloc(someSize)`.

   Either way, don't call `realloc(hello->p, someSize)` if `hello->p` is not initialized.
3. Well, it will only affect the `size` member of the object that hello refers to. If you change the `size` member, you probably also want to `realloc` `hello ->p` so that it match the size of `hello->size`. You can access the element of p with `hello->p[index]`. You can take the address of one element with `&hello->p[index]`.

### edit 2

Answering your comment here.

If you declare an array of mystructure as you commented (`mystructure hello[N];`), you access it with `hello[index].size` and `hello[index].p` and `hello[index1].p[index2]`.
This is because `hello[index]` is a struct;

To use the syntax `hello[index1]->p[index2]` (equivalent to `(*(hello[index1])).p[index2]`), you must declare an array of *pointers* to mystructure: `mystructure * hello[N]`, but then you must allocate memory for each N pointers:

```
for (size_t i=0; i<N; ++i) {
    hello[i] = malloc(sizeof(mystructure));
    /* todo: initialize hello[i]->size and hello[i]->p */
}
```

### original answer

Your struct definition won't compile because in the expression `int p[size]`, size must be known at compile time. It cannot be the `int size` member, because it is a variable. You could if you declared `int size` as a `const` and give it a value.

1. yes, and you can omit the parenthesis
2. you cannot `realloc` p because you didn't called `malloc` to allocate memory for it.
3. No, because of what I said first about your struct.

Comment: All the answers are very precise, but yours is the most complete. Thank you! One last question would be... What if hello would be an array of structures mystruct, like `mystructure hello[N]`. Would it be correct to refer the elements of `p` from a specific structure, as `hello[index]->p[index]` or `(*hello)[index].p[index]`?

Comment: Thanks again. Excuse me but... I don't see exactly why is needed a pointer to array `*hello[N]` instead of just `hello[N]` to use `hello[index1]->p[index2]`.

Comment: because `hello[N]` will reserve space for N *mystructure* elements. `hello[index]` will then have the type `mystructure`, not `mystructure*` (pointer to mystructure). So you will not be able to dereference a struct (with `->`), it won't compile. However, `*hello[N]` will reserve space for N "*pointers* to mystructure" elements. So `hello[index]` will be a pointer, that you can dereference (with `->`).

Comment: I understand. And when I need to free memory, would I have to do it first for each `*p`, or is it enough to free `hello`?

Comment: @AlexanderGeorge. As for allocation, you must free the `N` pointers. To free your array, each `malloc` call should be matched by a `free` call. Note that if you can go for the no-pointer version, it will be simpler, and faster (no allocation/deallocation).

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, if `hello` is a pointer you can access your `p` array like that: `(hello->p)[2]`.
2. You won't be able to `realloc` your p array. `p` is a static array (due to the declaration using [size]). If you want to be able to realloc it you will need to declare it as `int *p`.
3. You don't have to pass `hello` as a reference as long as it is already a pointer to a struct. If you modify it the struct will be modified everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, `(hello->p)[2]` or even just `hello->p[2]` will work to access elements of p.
2. You can't `realloc` statically allocated arrays, only dynamically allocated ones.
   If you wanted to be able to `realloc` `p` you would have to change `p` to a pointer to an integer:

   ```
   typedef struct {
       int size;
       int *p;
   } mystruct;
   ```
3. Yes. Remember that using a pointer to the struct is directly accessing the memory containing the struct. Any change you make to elements of the struct will be reflected to all places in the application that reference that memory location.